# Phaser 3 clearing up resources

Tags: phaser-framework

I have two scenes in the game and that loads few images on preload(). I need to know the correct way to clear loaded images & other resources when;

1. Browser tab is reloaded/closed
2. When loading images in a scene, if the key exists avoid loading that resource.

As of now, when my scene is reloaded(browser refresh) it gives the following error in console:

> Texture key already in use: main-lk

So what I tried was:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
    console.log("unloading window... try to unload cached images");
    game.cache = new this.Phaser.Cache.CacheManager(game);
    game.textures.destroy()
    game.destroy(false);
}
```

assuming that this will clear everything on a browser refresh. This doesn't seem to work cause I still get the same error.

Then I tried below code in preload()

```
this.textures.remove("main-aq"); <-- force removing the image
this.load.image("main-aq",[my url]); <-- reload the image
```

When I do that, console shows;

```
No texture found matching key: main-aq <--this is for removing line
Texture key already in use: main-aq <-- loading line. means this was not cleared with remove
```

How can I properly release resources onrefresh/reloading scenes ?

Comment: Hi, I've never need to clear the cache when someone reloading page. since phaser is gonna destroyed, cache is also gonna go so i'm guessing you don't need to do anything about it.

Comment: If you want to check for a resource in the textures manager, use 
const doesTextureExist = this.textures.exists(imageKey);

Comment: The source code doesn't seem to remove the key from the texture manager's list property in remove(key) like it does in removeKey(key). So try remove, then removeKey.


Link: https://github.com/photonstorm/phaser/blob/v3.22.0/src/textures/TextureManager.js#L181